# Accurate thread loop. Run a task with precise interval

Tags: java

I want my thread to perform an action 4 or 16 times per bpm (beats per minute). This timer is not 100% accurate, after a few seconds it desynchronizes from the metronome I found on youtube, and it gets a little slower than it should.

bpm = (float) my music bpm;

```
thread = new Thread(()->{
            long now ;
            long total ;
            while (true) {
                long bpmTime = (long) ((1000000000*60d)/(bpm*16));
                now = System.nanoTime();
                bpmTick(); //<-- my task
                try {
                    total = System.nanoTime() - now;
                    if(total > bpmTime) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Thread.sleep((bpmTime - (System.nanoTime() - now)) / 1000000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
```

I also tried:

```
Thread.sleep((long)(1000*(60.0/bpm)));
```

but the same problem occurs

In short, I need a metronome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some tips. Don't sleep for the amount of time you need to sleep. Sleeping has a granularity of maybe 10 ms or maybe significantly more (depending on your OS and the API, look it up for yours) so sleep for the amount you need minus the granularity. Then use a busy loop for the rest of the timing. There are probably some API for setting a smaller granularity, but don't know what OS you have and I am not that familiar with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to use is a `ScheduledExecutorService` instance instead. This class can repeat the task in a `Thread` repeatedly at a fixed rate. The class has a method called `scheduleAtFixedRate(task, intialDelay, DelayBetweenExecutions,TimeUnit)` just for this purpose.

When the initial delay is set to `0` the task will run as soon as `scheduleAtFixedRate` is called and will continue doing so until you call `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` on the service. Here's an example that uses some of your code:

```
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        int timesPerBPM = 16;
        long bpmTime = 900; //or whatever the outcome of your formula is.

        Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
            for (int i = 0; i < timesPerBPM; i++) //do task 16 times
                bpmTick(); //<-- my task
            });
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(thread, 0, bpmTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //This will start immediately because initialDelay is 0.
        executorService.shutdown(); //Always shutdown service when done to avoid memory leaks.
```

The `executorService` in the below code will run `bpmTick()` 16 times every 900 milliseconds. If it takes longer then 900 milliseconds to run `bpmTick()` 16 times the service will wait for the current task to complete until it starts the next repetition. So to keep things synchronized the 16 `bpmTick()` must always finish within `bpmTime` milliseconds. If you want to guarantee a 150 millisecond pause between threadtask executions *regardless of how long it takes to execute a task* then you should use the method `scheduleWithFixedDelay()` instead.

If you want the service to repeat the task every minute instead of every 900 milliseconds then it is best to change `bpmTime` to 1 and `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS` to `TimeUnit.MINUTES`.

Comment: Thank you! I used nanoseconds to be more precise:

`thread.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::bpmTick, 0,(long) ((1000000000*60d)/(bpm*bpmDivisor)), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);`